# How can I minimise the false positives?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python

I have 50,000 samples. Of these 23,000 belong to the desired class $A$. I can sacrifice the number of instances that are classified as belonging to the desired class $A$. It will be enough for me to get 7000 instances in the desired class $A$, provided that most of these instances classified as belonging to $A$ really belong to the desired class $A$. How can I do this?

The following is the confusion matrix in the case the instances are perfectly classified.

```
[[23000   0]
 [  0 27000]]
```

But it is unlikely to obtain this confusion matrix, so I'm quite satisfied with the following confusion matrix.

```
[[7000   16000]
 [  500 26500]]
```

I am currently using the `sklearn` library. I mainly use algorithms based on decision trees, as they are quite fast in the calculation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! I've reformulated part of your post to make it clearer. Make sure I've not changed the intended meaning.

Comment: I have two classes. I'm only interested in the first one.
As a rule the desired class is called positive.
It is important to me that in the positive class got as 
little as possible false negative labels that are predicted.
I added two examples with a confusion matrix.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've provided an answer below. I may edit it later to provide a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the minimization of *false positives*, that is, the instances that are classified as belonging to the desired class (the *positive* part of *false positives*) but that do not actually belong to that class (the *false* part of *false positives*). In practice, given your constraints, you may want to maximize the [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), while maintaining a good [recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html).

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000619/3924118) to the question [How can the model be tuned to improve precision, when precision is much more important than recall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29994694/3924118), the user suggests performing a grid search (using [`sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring="precision")`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)) to find the parameters of the model that maximize the precision. See also the question [Classifier with adjustable precision vs recall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/140266/82135).

Comment: Thanks! Some things already done.
I have an opinion that basically algorithms try to separate both classes to the maximum.
I don't have to do that, it's enough that as few false negatives as possible get into the desired class.